# How to start Skype Application through Delphi 7 (using a Delphi command)

Tags: delphi, command, skype

What kind of command should i use?

```
shellexecute  ?
```

I am having trouble writing down the path.

Comment: The preferred API to start a new process is `CreateProcess`. If you want to start a process though, you need to know where it lives. How do you propose working out where the executable is installed?

Comment: Yeah, it seems i'll have to add edittext to select a directory: `var
  temp: string;
begin
  SelectDirectory('Select Source Dir','',temp);
  Edit1.Text:=temp;
  Edit1.Hint:=temp;
end;`

Comment: Perhaps you can read the location out of the registry

Comment: For example look here: http://brcline.com/blog/?tag=skype